# Add Form field value to the URL on submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, url

I have a form where the user input has to be send to another website in the URL.

I have tried it this way:

```
<form onsubmit="window.location = 'http://example.com/en/' + city.value + '/apartments/listing/1?arrivalDate=' + from.value + '&departureDate=' + till.value + '&numPer=' + persons.value; return false; + '/' ">
```

But this opens the webpage in the same tab. Is there another way to achieve something like this? Maybe with PHP?

Comment: you can try target="_blank"

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with window.location. I tried to use window.open but this does not allow me to add the form fields in the URL. Or does it?

Comment: Why not use the `GET` method and set the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using

```
<form onsubmit="window.open('http://example.com/en/' + place.value + '/apartments/listing/1?arrivalDate=' + from.value + '&departureDate=' + till.value + '&numPer=' + persons.value); return false;">
```

I did not know I could use the form variables with `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GET` method for `form` -

```
<form action="path_to_submit" method="GET" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Does this method allow me to open the website in a new tab?

Comment: Yup. Just add `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could write up the form:

```
<form action="http://url/to/send/data/to.com" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The 'action' attribute takes the url you wish to send form data to and the 'method' attribute accepts the request mode (GET or POST etc.). 'method' is set to GET by default and you may skip it completely if you so wish. The 'target' attribute will open a new tab if set to "_blank".

Let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: _1._ How can you know he needs a `POST` request? _2._ The default method is not `POST`, but `GET` ([more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)).

Comment: My bad on count# 2. Default is GET indeed.
#1. Since he had mentioned that "user data" will be sent to another "website" - for obvious basic security reasons, POST is what I believe he should be using.